# How to auto-close a not active tab (which is in background) after appearing download dialog pop-up using javascript? (besides setTimeout)

Tags: javascript

A tab is opened by script so it may be auto-closed.
setTimeout is not a solution (in that tab will be many redirects).
The next code works only for active tab. Need an analog which may work for background tabs or how to change this to work for not active tabs? (Chrome)

```
window.focus();
window.onblur = function() {window.close()}
```

Comment: What do you mean, not active tabs?

Comment: "Not active tabs" = tabs in background (only one may be "active").

Answer (score 0):

If there is a new script running on that page just set it up like:

```
window.addEventListener("blur", window.close);
```

I first thought ... **BUT**: *Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.*

Or close it / attach an event listener the window from within the same script you opened it:

```
let foo = window.open("https://localhost");
foo.addEventListener("blur", foo.close); // simply foo.close() also works
```

If you meant something different please write a comment, Elias :)

Comment: Of course I know about setTimeout. Need something another which may to auto-close right away after any time.
The first url is different for each time. And there are many redirects in that tab. So the second string is not suitable.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("blur", window.close)`
it works in the same way as
`window.onblur = function() {window.close()}`
They work if a tab is active. But the point is to work for background tabs. The problem is that in background - window is already "blur". So detection can't work. Maybe need some another attribute besides "blur"...

Comment: For what event do you want it to detect? In my chrome it auto focuses new tabs with `window.open()` but if that's not the case you could try `let foo = window.open(); foo.focus()`

Comment: As long the call is not cross-origin pretty much every thing is possible... e.g: you can do `foo = window.open("./downloads"); foo.console.log("bar")` should work no problem if **not** cross-origin

Comment: Url is always different. So window.open() is not a variant.
The even to detect is appearing of dialog download window. It may be detected with "blur". But it can't work for background tabs because seems that they can't be focused in background. So they can't be detected by "blur" because they are already "blur". The point is in background tabs (for active it works).

Comment: Still no a solution (((